# Fresh install of SQL Server 2022 Express on Windows 2019 very slow running selects

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, windows-server-2019

I restored a database from SQL Server 2016 Express on a Windows 2012 server and now the selects are taking ages to run. Everything worked fine on SQL Server 2016 Express.

This is a new Windows 2019 server (8GB RAM, Intel Xeon Processor (4 CPUs), ~2.5GHz) and SQL Server 2022 Express install.

Windows Defender Antivirus Service is installed but as I am renting the server I am unable to stop it.

```
select * 
from question with (NOLOCK) 
where quizId = 100
```

takes less than 1 second to run

```
select * 
from question with (NOLOCK) 
where quizId = 100 
order by displayno
```

This however takes 25 seconds to run on new server but runs instantly on the old server.

Does anyone know if I need to change some settings to get the selects to work as they did before?

Thanks.

Comment: question as it stands lacks sufficient detail. Did you rebuild statistics?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure what extra information you require. Yes I rebuilt statistics with no help. I am just wondering if there is some setting on SQL that needs to be changed after a fresh install. I have 2 tables, Quiz and Topic. Topic has 2 fields TopicId (Index) and Topic Name. Quiz has lots of fields including TopicId. TopicId on the quiz table is a non-clustered index. Now if I run an inner join on these tables it takes 8 seconds to return 30k rows. This is just one example of how all queries with joins are taking ages to run.

Comment: "Windows Defender Antivirus Service is installed but as I am renting the server " -  why would you rent Express?  Limitations of SQL Server Express:
1GB maximum memory used by the database engine
10GB maximum database size
1MB maximum buffer cache
CPU the lesser of one (1) socket or four (4) cores (number of SQL user connections NOT limited). If your VM is configured as N sockets, 1 Core per socket. then you only get 1 core.

Comment: SQL Express is free and was used on the old server and all worked fine. The server is a rented virtual server

Comment: Yes I know it's free. There's a reason it's free.

Comment: your comments do not contribute any valuable information to solving my current issue you just recommend I buy SQL professional which I can't

Comment: Please provide query plans for the queries, so it's possible to see what's the matter.  Use pastetheplan website. There's no "go-faster" switch in sql server 2022 that i know of

Comment: @tfa : at no point did I recommend you buy SQL professional. If pointing out the limitations that SQL Express has that might be contributing to your problem is not helpful, well I'm done here.

Answer (score -1):

The answer table has 8 million records and I found the query that bottlenecked the system.

I changed this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.answer INNER JOIN dbo.question ON dbo.answer.questionId = dbo.question.questionId  where question.quizId = @quizId ORDER BY dbo.answer.answerId
```

To this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.answer INNER JOIN dbo.question ON dbo.answer.questionId = dbo.question.questionId  where question.quizId = @quizId ORDER BY dbo.question.questionId, dbo.answer.answerId
```

I do not know why this caused an issue in SQL Express 2022 and not in SQL Express 2016